# Parametric lines integral

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals, line-integrals

I've been trying to make sense of this for days now, but I can't seem to be able to!

**How does this**

> Let $t$ be a parameter equal to the distance from the beginning of the polygonal
> line till the current point along this line. Let $l_{j_{1}}$ and $l_{j_{2}}$ be values of the parameter defining the beginning and the end of the analyzed part of the
> polygonal line. The horizontal line approximating a given part of the polygonal
> line can be defined as
> $$y=\frac{V_{y}}{l_{j_{2}}-{l_{j_{1}}}}, V_{y}=\int_{{l_{j_{1}}}}^{{l_{j_{2}}}} y(t)dt$$
> The vertical line can be found similarly
> $$x=\frac{V_{x}}{l_{j_{2}}-{l_{j_{1}}}}, V_{x}=\int_{{l_{j_{1}}}}^{{l_{j_{2}}}} x(t)dt$$

**Make these straight lines ($L_{i}$) [image: here]**

What should I plug in as $t$ ? Should I plug in the last point's length?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. You end by asking "What should I plug in as $t$?", but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate? Or do you just not understand the geometric intuition of the construction?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for in-lining the image and editing the question. I guess I don't understand how to make a line from these integrals! Is $t$ a continuous variable here? If so, I'll get infinite numbers as the result and what would be the correct input to get a line that covers those fragments?

Comment: It wasn't me who made the edits.

Comment: Okay then shout out to anyone who did! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of the "*average value of a function*"?

For a function $f(x)$, the "*average vale of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$*" is defined as
$$ \mathrm{avg} = \frac{1}{b-a} \, \int_a^b f(x) \, dx $$

If you evaluate this integral, you get a number (a constant), let's call it $c$. Then graphing the horizontal line $y=c$ will show you the average height of the graph between $x=a$ and $x=b$.

This is what is being described in the quote from your post. You have a parameterized curve $r(t) = (x(t), \, y(t))$. Then the quantities:
$$ \frac{1}{j_2-j_1} \; \int_{j_1}^{j_2} x(t) \, dt \hspace{0.5cm} \text{ and } \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{1}{j_2-j_1} \; \int_{j_1}^{j_2} y(t) \, dt $$
are just the average $x$-value and average $y$-value of all the points along the curve between times $t=j_1$ and $t=j_2$. In the picture the horizontal and vertical lines are just plotting the equations $x=\mathrm{const}$ and $y = \mathrm{const}$, where "const" is the value of the appropriate integral.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained but I still don't know what to plug in as $t$ ! Suppose I have $[j_{1}=0, j_{2}=5]$ I should plug in $5$ to get the average of all values, right?

Comment: Where are you trying to plug in $t$? Plug it into what? On the interval $[0,5]$, you would evaluate the integrals $C = \frac{1}{5} \int_0^5 x(t) \, dt$ and $D = \frac{1}{5} \int_0^5 y(t) \, dt$.  These would give you the lines $x=C$ and $y=D$.

Comment: In the paper it says " The parametric description of the source line is $(x(t), y(t)), t\in[0,T])$ where $(x(t), y(t))$ are the **coordinates**, $t$ is the distance between the beginning and the current point of the polyline measured along the polyline, $T$ is the polyline length " given this, if I have a fragment of zigzags starting at coords $(1,1)$ and ending at $(5,5)$ I'd like to find a straight line that approximates this zigzag using the formulas above. What should I plugin as $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ according to the quantities you mentioned to get that constant number?

Comment: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions, the parametric equations for the "zig-zag". If you plug in $t=0$, you will get $(1,1)$ in your example (the beginning point), and if you plug in $t=T$, you will get $(5,5)$, the ending point. To evaluate the integrals, you don't plug in values for $t$. When you do an integral $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt$, you don't actually think about plugging in things for $t$. I still don't completely understand the question.

Comment: My question in its basic form is that how do I get that constant $c$ given some sample data? Suppose we have $t=[0, 5]$ as the interval and at $t=5$ we have coordinates $(3,4)$ (since $t$ is measured *along* the length of the polyline from the beginning and there is a zigzag, we won't necessarily end up at $(5,5)$ at $t=5$). To get that constant $c$ should I do it like $V_{x}=\int_{0}^{5} 3dt$ for $x$ and $V_{y}=\int_{0}^{5} 4dt$ for $y$?

Comment: You need to know the parameterization $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ to be able to do the integral. It is not enough to know the endpoints. You need to know precisely what the "zig-zag" looks like in between. I couldn't say more unless your example was more specific. I suggest editing your question if you want a detailed calculation as your answer.